# Find password in file

Tags: php, security, file-io

I have a piece of php code that upon a page load request finds a corresponding file which contains information about the page including the password.

The syntax in the file is as follows:

```
Pagename: 
PageInfo:
Password: SecretPassword
```

How would I get around finding the password following the Password:?

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$filepath = absolute_url("page/info.php");  
$infoFile = fopen("$filepath", "r");
$contents = stream_get_contents($infoFile);
```

Comment: you're fetching a password via unprotected http from a file? what's the url of your site so I can steal all the passwords?

Comment: and the rest of the code? :)

Comment: Use `file_get_contents()` and `str_getcsv($text, ':')` to get a paired list to look at. (A regex would be simpler though.)

Comment: use regex: Password:(.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a very strange way to store the data. Assuming this can't be helped though, you could RegEx this with something like:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/Password:\s(.*)$/', $contents, $matches);
//                     ^ Assuming there's only ever 1 space
```

`echo $matches[1]` will print `SecretPassword`

Comment: Thanks. What should I change if I want it to read the password until a  new line og a specific symbol occurs? At the moment I can't have anything "underneath" the password...

Comment: You can remove the `$` at the end or change the RegEx to include the special char outside the parenthesis.